# Countryman type is a Specker type: an unclear point in the proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, well-orders

I continue reading that book on exercises from set theory:
[Here](http://62.182.86.140/main/3000/72a0013cf196b69a2f994aea4e8860a6/%28Problem%20books%20in%20mathematics%29%20Peter%20Komjath%2C%20Vilmos%20Totik%20-%20Problems%20and%20Theorems%20in%20Classical%20Set%20Theory-Springer%20%282006%29.pdf) on the page 112 they define a Countryman type. On the page
439 they go on to prove that every Countryman is Specker. I have a problem to understand
some parts of the proof: first, why there must be $\alpha < \alpha'$ with $i(\alpha)=i(\alpha')$ ? Second why such $\beta$ and $\beta'$ can be found ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existence of such $\alpha$ and $\alpha'$ is just Pigeonhole again.  There are $\aleph_1$ different values of $\alpha$ but only $\aleph_0$ possible values of $i(\alpha)$ so there must exist distinct $\alpha$ and $\alpha'$ with $i(\alpha)=i(\alpha')$, and you may assume without loss of generality that $\alpha<\alpha'$.

Since $i(\alpha')=i$, there are uncountably many different $\beta'$ such that $\langle \alpha',\beta'\rangle\in A_i$, so just pick one of them.  Then since $i(\alpha)=i$, there are also uncountably many $\beta$ such that $\langle \alpha,\beta\rangle\in A_i$.  In particular, there is such a $\beta$ which is greater than $\beta'$, since there are only countably many ordinals less than $\beta'$.

Comment: Nice explanation. It's pity that I'm unable to solve such a thing on my own.